# FormulaR1C1 sumIF delete duplcates + concatenate

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the below code to work for my sheet.

```
Sub main()
Dim helperRng As Range, dataRng As Range
Dim colToFilter As String
Dim colsToSumUp As Long

With Worksheets("Transactions") '<== change "Sheet01" as per your actual sheet name
Set dataRng = .Range("A3:K3").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
colToFilter = "A" ' set here the column header you want to sum up on
colsToSumUp = 5 ' number of adjacent columns to sum up with
Set helperRng = dataRng.Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1) 'localize "helper" cells 
first column out of sheet used range
With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC" & Cells(1, colToFilter).Column 'make a copy of the values you want to sum up on
    .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(R1C[-1]:RC[-1], RC[-1])=1,1,"""")" 'localize with "1" first occurrence of each unique value
    With .Offset(, 2).Resize(, colsToSumUp)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=sumif(C" & helperRng.Column & ", RC" & helperRng.Column & ",C[" & Cells(1, colToFilter).Column - helperRng.Column - 1 & "])" 'sum up in adjacent columns
        .Value = .Value 'get rid of formulas
    End With
    .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete 'delete rows with repeted values you want to sum up on
    dataRng.Columns(2).Resize(.Rows.Count, colsToSumUp).Value = .Offset(, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count, colsToSumUp).Value 'copy summed up values from "helper" cells
    helperRng.Resize(, 1 + 1 + colsToSumUp).Clear 'clear "helper" cells
End With

End With

End Sub
```

Basically i want ik to search for duplicates in column A and sum up the values in column E and concatenate tekst in columns F:J

[image]

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: I can't figure out how to only sum values in Column E